# Is that possible implement the same code but only enabled when imported the jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, interface, implementation

Is that possible implement the same code but only enabled when adding a dependency to SpringBoot project?
If possible, how to achieve it?

I want to implement the code like this:

```java
     DoSomethingUtil doSomethingUtil = new DoSomethingUtil();
     doSomethingUtil.send("API URL", "System A", "Hello");
```

It would do nothing when project didn't add the implement of the DoSomethingUtil.java.

After adding to pom.xml that which would implement the DoSomethingUtil.java, it would really do something.

Comment: What you appear to be describing is adding a dependency, not "importing" something.

Comment: Please describe the context specifically , You want to add this library to normal maven project or springboot project ?

Comment: Sure this is possible and there are several mechanisms for this. One could be Java's `ServiceLoader`, another might be dependency injection (or lookup) as provided by Spring etc. Most of those approaches require some change to your code though: 1) you need an interface your code knows at runtime 2) the library/service implements that interface 3) your code first checks whether it can acquire an implementation of the interface before trying to call a method on it. I suggest you read up on the approaches and grab a tutorial as explaining everything here might be too much for SO.

Comment: It's spring boot project, and i want to keep options of a add-on jar on my several projects. Sorry for my poor english and not specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you don't need to know about `DoSomethingUtil` anywhere else in your code, you can run something on it only if it's present in your classpath (without importing it) if you use reflection all the way:

```
try {
    Class<?> dsuClass = Class.forName("do.something.util.DoSomethingUtil");
    Object dsuInstance = dsyClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
    Method sendMethod = dsuClass.getDecaredMethod("send", String.class, String.class, String.class);
    sendMethod.invoke(dsuInstance, "API URL", "System A", "Hello");
} catch (Exception ignored) {}
```

You may want to revisit the poor error handling above to distinguish (at least) between class not being present in the classpath and `send()` method invocation failure.

Answer (score 0):

What you appear to be describing is adding a dependency, not "importing" something.

Will it work?

Sort of.  What you *could* do is overlay the definition of `the.pkg.DoSomethingUtil` with another version of `the.pkg.DoSomethingUtil` in a different JAR file.  It *can* work, but it makes your application sensitive to the order of the JARs on the *runtime* classpath.  That makes your application fragile ... to say the least.

You can probably make this work with classic Java if you have full control of the runtime classpath.  However:

- I'm not sure if it will work with SpringBoot.
- If you tried this sort of thing on Android, the APK builder would protest.  It treats the scenario of two classes with the same full name as an error.

---

I think there is a better solution:

1. Refactor the code so that there is a `DoSomethingUtil` interface and two classes; e.g. `RealDoSomethingUtil` and `DummyDoSomethingUtil`.
2. Replace `new DoSomethingUtil()` with a call to a factory method.
3. Implement the factory method something like this:

   ```
   private static Class<?> doSomethingClass;

   public static synchronized DoSomethingUtil makeDoSomethingUtil() {
       if (doSomethingClass == null) {
           try {
               doSomethingClass = Class.forName("the.pkg.RealDoSomethingUtil");
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               doSomethingClass = the.pkg.DummyDoSomethingUtil.class;
           }
       }
       return (DoSomethingUtil) (doSomethingClass.newInstance());
   }
   ```
4. Put `RealDoSomethingUtil` into the add-on JAR file, and `DoSomethingUtil`, `RealDoSomethingUtil` and the factory method into the main JAR file.

You should probably make the exception handling more selective so that it deals with different classloader errors differently.  For example, if `RealDoSomethingUtil` exists but can't be loaded, you probably should log that ... or maybe let the exception crash the application.

---

You could also make use of `ServiceLoader`, but I don't know if it would be simpler ...

Answer (score 0):

The java [Service Provide API (SPI)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html) is there to detect wether implementation(s) of an interface exists.

- You have a jar with an interface `DoSomethingUtil` in your application.
- Possibly on the class path an implementation jar (`MyDoSomethingUtilImpl implements DoSomethingUtil`), with an entry in META-INF/services.
- You must check whether the interface is implemented.
- One could make a fallback implementation.